# unable to change string file for other languages. It takes always default string file

Tags: android, string, locale

Am using below code to change other language inside my. But It always taking default string file after language change inside app. Also in studio new other language string file is created in same values folder. Pls help me. here am passing locale "ms-rMY" for malay. I tried with "ms" also. check below code

```
public void updateLocale(String language) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

        finish();
        Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(refresh);
    }
```

Comment: your code seems ok, maybe the problem is in your values-xx folder, could you try with something easier like values-fr and then set the locale to "fr"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create local object Like this

```
Local myLocale = new Locale("ms", "MY");
```

This constructor allows you to create a Locale object with language, country.

Answer (score 0):

The Android system always takes the language set in the settings on the device. If you change it this way it will only keep that language in one activity. So you will need to change the local in the onCreate of a activity (every time).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    //change the locale
}
```

Comment: @iffu You can't start a activity after changing the locale. This will make it go back to the system language. You need to start the activity and then change the locale.